# Cassandra IN Query using Accessor interfaces

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I'm unable to find a way to get list of rows given Ids using Accessor Interface. Please let me what i'm doing wrong here.

```
@Accessor
public interface UserAccessor {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id in (?)")
    ListenableFuture<Result<User>> getByIdsAsync(List<UUID> ids);
}
```

I'm getting the below error when getByIdsAsync method is called. I tried changing the parameter type from List to String of comma separated UIDs but still seeing the same error.

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: UUID should be 16 or 0 bytes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must remove the parenthesis around the marker:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id in ?")
```